# Swapping backslash and backspace keybindings Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I prefer backspace right above "enter". In windows this can be accomplished with autohotkey. On my desktop a HKKB keyboard has this layout built-in.

Following [Custom keyboard layouts (Ubuntu)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) has me swapping `<BKSL>` and `<BKSB>` in `usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`. This yields the behavior that both backspace and backslash enter a backslash, rather than swapping the keys functionality. Swapping via `xcape -e 'BackSpace=backslash'` and its alternate will insert then delete a backspace.

How can backspace and backslash be swapped in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo -e "keycode 22 = backslash \n keycode 51 = BackSpace" | xmodmap -
```

Comment: Almost perfect, how to get "shift+BackSpace" to return bar? The modifier doesn't translate.